# How to url decode a POST request in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, urldecode

I have a NodeJS proxy that takes in a request, does some obfuscation, and then passes on the request to another server.  Recently we needed to make a change to introduce another proxy we don't own, and it looks like this proxy is causing the request to be double url encoded.  As a temporary workaround I want to decode the body of the request when necessary (this new proxy will exist in some environments, not in others). I've looked around for how to do this, and it seems like 'decodeURIComponent' is what I want, but I'm getting a malformedURI exception when I try to use that, so I'm wondering if I'm using it wrong, or it's just not appropriate for this case.

Attempting to url decode request body:

```
  decodeDoubleEncodedBuffer = function(buffer) {
    var buffString;
    if (Buffer.isBuffer(buffer)) {
      buffString = buffer.toString();
    } else {
      buffString = buffer;
    }
    if (Config.requireURLDecode) {
      return new Buffer(decodeURIComponent(buffString));
    } else {
      return new Buffer(buffString);
    }
  };
```

...

```
  body = new Buffer(0)
  req.addListener('data', function(chunk) {
    return body = Buffer.concat([body, decodeDoubleEncodedBuffer(chunk)]);
  });
```

With this I get the following error:

```
 return new Buffer(decodeURIComponent(buffString));
                                      ^
    URIError: URI malformed at decodeURIComponent (native)
    ...
```

The original listener code being modified which works fine is below

```
body = new Buffer(0);

req.addListener('data', function(chunk) {
  return body = Buffer.concat([body, Buffer.isBuffer(chunk) ? chunk : new Buffer(chunk)]);
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I realized two things, maybe 3 if you count "I'm dumb".  1) the content in the body was gzipped json and what I had works fine if it's unzipped, 2)  the content I wanted to decode WAS in the url, and not in the body...which makes sense why it was getting encoded by anything in the first place.  I don't know if it's ever normal for a post body to be percent encoded, but either way I feel stupid lol.

So I guess the answer is, the code I provided would work fine for valid url characters.